# Android set new size to layout

Tags: android

i have some problem with programmatically layoyt resize. I have layout

```
<RelativeLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:background="@android:color/black"
                      android:visibility="visible"
                      android:id="@+id/lb_lobby_center_layout" >

            <include layout="@layout/lb_top_banner"
                     android:layout_height="115dp"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/lb_top_menu_parent"
                    />
            <include layout="@layout/lb_top_menu"
                     android:layout_height="65dp"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />
            <include layout="@layout/lb_ctg_game"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/lb_top_banner_ll_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

In onTouch() method of lb_ctg_game i movie layout lb_top_banner up on axis Y.
layout lb_ctg_game must take this free place. I can change topMargin of lb_ctg_game, but I can't resize it's height. I have free place in the bottom.

```
 private void replaceView(int deltaY)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bannersParam = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) disappearView.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameContainerParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gameContainer.getLayoutParams();
    int top =0, bottom = 0;
    if (isGoUp)
    {
        top = disappearView.getTop();
        bottom = disappearView.getBottom();
        if ((bottom - deltaY) > topBorder)
        {
            bannersParam.topMargin = top - deltaY;
            bannersParam.bottomMargin = bottom - deltaY;
            //disappearView.setLayoutParams(params2);
            disappearView.layout(disappearView.getLeft(),bannersParam.topMargin,disappearView.getRight(),bannersParam.bottomMargin);
            //disappearView.requestLayout();
            gameContainerParams.topMargin =bannersParam.bottomMargin;
            int yyy = gameContainer.getBottom() + deltaY;
            //gameContainer.setLayoutParams(listParams);
            gameContainer.layout(gameContainer.getLeft(),gameContainerParams.topMargin,gameContainer.getRight(),yyy);//gameContainer.getBottom()
            //layout(getLeft(),getTop(),getRight(),yyy);//getBottom()
            gameContainer.forceLayout();
            //gameContainer.requestLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            bannersParam.bottomMargin = topBorder -10;
            bannersParam.topMargin= bannersParam.bottomMargin -  disappearView.getHeight();
            disappearView.layout(disappearView.getLeft(),bannersParam.topMargin,disappearView.getRight(),bannersParam.bottomMargin);
            //disappearView.requestLayout();
            gameContainerParams.topMargin =topBorder;
            int yyy = gameContainer.getBottom() + disappearView.getHeight();
            //yyy = listParams.topMargin+yyy;
            //gameContainer.setLayoutParams(gameContainerParams);
            int th = gameContainer.getHeight();
            gameContainer.layout(gameContainer.getLeft(),gameContainerParams.topMargin,gameContainer.getRight(),yyy);//
            //layout(getLeft(),getTop(),getRight(),yyy);//getBottom()

            gameContainer.forceLayout();
            //gameContainer.requestLayout();

            //this.forceLayout();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int d = getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (getFirstVisiblePosition() != 0)
            return;
        top = disappearView.getTop();
        bottom = disappearView.getBottom();
        if ((top + deltaY)<topBorder)
        {
            bannersParam.topMargin = top + deltaY;
            bannersParam.bottomMargin = bottom + deltaY;
            //disappearView.setLayoutParams(params2);
            disappearView.layout(disappearView.getLeft(),bannersParam.topMargin,disappearView.getRight(),bannersParam.bottomMargin);
            disappearView.forceLayout();
            gameContainerParams.topMargin =bannersParam.bottomMargin;
            gameContainer.layout(gameContainer.getLeft(), gameContainerParams.topMargin, gameContainer.getRight(), gameContainer.getBottom());
            //layout(getLeft(),listParams.topMargin,getRight(),getBottom());
            gameContainer.forceLayout();
           // gameContainer.invalidate();

        }
        else
        {
            bannersParam.topMargin= initionalY;
            bannersParam.bottomMargin = bannersParam.topMargin +  disappearView.getHeight();
            disappearView.layout(disappearView.getLeft(),bannersParam.topMargin,disappearView.getRight(),bannersParam.bottomMargin);
            disappearView.forceLayout();
            gameContainerParams.topMargin = bannersParam.bottomMargin;
            int yyy = gameContainer.getBottom();
            gameContainer.layout(gameContainer.getLeft(), gameContainerParams.topMargin, gameContainer.getRight(), gameContainer.getBottom());
            //layout(getLeft(),listParams.topMargin,getRight(),getBottom());
            gameContainer.forceLayout();
           // gameContainer.invalidate();

        }

    }
}
```